# Send mail notification of pull request to cross domain users using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, office365, azure-powershell, pull-request, email-notifications

I am working in a team, I am admin of Azure devops, and I have a requirement, I want to send a email notification of every pull request created by my developers team.

But problem is that my all developers don't have email domain access in my client's Azure devops.

My mean is my client name for example is ABC so being admin client given me access by giving email id with admin authorization ashishjain@abc.com but developers don't have this mail domains (because we are vendors and working for client). In addition my client don't use full features of office 365.

Challenge is, how can i send a mail notification of every pull request using my client's Azure devops to my developers  who don't have mail IDs like abc.com.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a notification you can specify the email address (**any** email address):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What kind of mail ID do they have to access your Azure DevOps? Even though different from @abc.com, such as `xx@123.com`, they should also be able to access their own E-mail `xx@123.com`

To be honestly, your requirement sounds like a little weird. According to your description, `every pull request created by my developers team`. These users should already been team members in your org.

You just need to [Manage notifications for a team or group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/howto-manage-team-notifications?view=azure-devops) in your project. For example:

- *Team preference:* use the team's default delivery preference.

  [image]

Learn [how to manage delivery settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/howto-manage-team-notifications?view=azure-devops#manage-team-delivery-settings).

If those develops are also not able to access their own sign-in E-mail address system. They cloud [change their preferred email address for notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/change-email-address?view=azure-devops).

> You can change your preferred email address for notifications from
>   your organization preferences profile page. **Notifications are sent
>   by default to the preferred email address for your organization
>   profile**. This is typically the email address you signed into Azure
>   DevOps Services  with.

Besides, you could also set any **Custom email address:** recipient is the specified email address in **delivery options** of your team notification.

Lastly, the E-mail which sent to develops notifications will not be the one who created the subscription. It hands by Azure DevOps Server.